# HAXM won't run after deleting the file in the LaunchAgents/LaunchDaemons

Tags: android, macos-sierra, haxm

After i deleted the file for HAXM from

```
/Library/LaunchAgents
```

or

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons
```

or

```
/Users/t/Library/LaunchAgents
```

or

```
Login Items
```

I'm not exactly sure where it was, but it was in one of the above. Now even if i uninstall it and install again through the "Android SDK Manager" it work start. I get this error:

```
2017-05-19 09:31:57.615 HAXM installation[1057:199982] AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges failed with return: -60031
2017-05-19 09:31:57.615 HAXM installation[1057:199982] HAXM installation failed!
```

After running this:

```
/Users/t/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/HAXM\ installation
```

Comment: Why -1? Comment should be made required here on down-vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it but mounting the "IntelHAXM_6.1.1.dmg" in "/Users/t/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager".

After a successful install i got the "/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.intel.haxm.plist" file which i deleted back.

Here are the contents of the file, just in case someone else should delete it like me and just needed this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <false/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.intel.haxm</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/Library/Extensions/intelhaxm.kext/Contents/Resources/haxm_start.sh</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>root</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```